# Pushing array in js asynchronus dont work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to push the users array with the dirs. But the `dir` property is still blank in the console.log statement after this.
Have an Idea? I know i could just use a synchronus function but friend told me, synchronus functions are blocking all other stuff going on.

```
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const db = req.db;
    const query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    const users = [];

    db.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){
            users.push(results[i]);
            users[i].dir = [];
            fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'userdata', results[i].username), (err, entries) => {
                users[i].dir.push(entries[i]);
            });

        }
        console.log(users);
        res.render("admin", {
            user: req.session.user,
            dbUsers: users,
        });
    });
});
```

So i just updated my code. But it dont works either.

Comment: Asynchronous!  You need to read and understand what an asynchronous callback means and how it behaves in node.js.  Your `for` loop runs to completion, you call `res.render()` and then, sometime later, your `fs.readdir()` callbacks fire, long after the rest of your code is done.

Comment: I edited my code.. :D

Comment: I was going to offer you the most modern nodejs solution using promises and even ES7 `async/await`, but I ran into trouble in writing the code because this line of code `users[i].dir.push(entries[i]);` makes no sense to me.  You're somehow only collection the `i`th item from a user-specific directory listing?  This means you think directory listing are in a precise order and you want a different item from every user's directory?  That is very weird and does not seem likely that it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readdir` is async function, which means that the loop will not wait until the `readdir` function finishes and then continue to the next iteration, try to use `fs.readdirSync` to make it synchronous, or you can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module:

```
for(let i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){
    users.push(results[i]);

    let entries = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'userdata', results[i].username));

    users[i].dir = entries;
}
```

[Async module](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.htm) solution:

```
async.eachOf( results, function(user, i, next) {

    users.push(user);

    fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'userdata', user.username), (err, entries) => {

        // if error pass it to the last callback
        if (err) return next(err);

        user.dir = entries;

        // iteration done
        next();
    });


}, function (err) {

    // this function is executed only when all iteration done

    if (err) {
        throw err;
        return res.send('error occured');
    }

    res.render("admin", {
        user: req.session.user,
        dbUsers: users,
    });

});
```

Comment: Okay, thanks I will try the Async function in 15 mins

Comment: Okay i have a question. What is this parameter i ? Is this like the i in the for loop?

Comment: Yes it is, go to this [link](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf) to know how `eachOf` works

Comment: Ok now it says at users[0].dir = "test" but i have 2 dirs and on the second user it says undefined

Comment: That's because `entries[i] ` return one dir, try `user.dir = entries;`

Comment: But then i should do user[i].dir = entries or not?

Comment: `user.dir = entries;` for the second example, `users[i].dir = entries;` for the first example, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

As @jfriend00 mentioned, you need to research about asynchronous operations.

I refactored your code using promises for the asynchronous calls. You could make it a little bit easier to read by using await.

```
const queryUsers = (db) => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    db.query(query, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            return reject(error);
        }

        resolve(results);
    });
});

const getUserFiles = username => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'userdata', username), (err, entries) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }

        resolve(entries);
    });
});

const getUsersFiles = users => Promise.all(
    users.map(user => getUserFiles(user.username)
        .then(files => ({ ...user, dir: files })))
);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    queryUsers(req.db)
        .then(getUsersFiles)
        .then(users => {
            console.log(users);
            res.render("admin", {
                user: req.session.user,
                dbUsers: users,
            });
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you console out the value of `i` in this line `users[i].dir.push(entries[i]);` I'm going to guess that it is the max numbered item +1 every time, because the `fs.readdir` call is asynchronous, the value of `i` will not match up with what is expected. try using a value in a closure like this. when the closure is created the value of `i` is saved to the closure as `idx`.

```
 for(let i = 0; i < results.length ; i++){
        (idx => {
            users.push(results[idx]);
            users[idx].dir = [];
            fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname,'..', 'userdata', results[i].username), (err, entries) => {
                users[idx].dir.push(entries[idx]);
            });
        })(i);
 }
```

Comment: The issue is that `fs.readdir()` is asynchronous so the OP's code has no way of knowing when they are all done and when they can use the array of results.

Comment: I understand that in principle but if there is no other action taking place afterwords, the above code ensures that data lands in the right place, can you paste an answer that illustrates your solution to handling the asynch nature of fs.readdir?

Comment: The OP is trying to use the `users` array in their `res.render()`.  That's the action they want and the problem they have.  Your answer does not show how to do that.

Comment: Of course i can log out i, i get results[i] in the console

Comment: what is the output of `results[i]` what does it equal. can you post the console.log code and the output